Multi-processing code not working in while loop
Happy Sunday.
I have this code that I want to run using the multi-processing module. But it doesn't just work for some reason.
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    while True:
        if LOCAL_RUN:
            print("ALERT: Doing a local run of the automation with limited capabilities.")

        list_of_clients = db_manager.get_clients()
        random.shuffle(list_of_clients)

        list_of_not_attempted_clients_domains = db_manager.tags()
        group_of_clients_handlers = {}

        # no matches
        if not list_of_not_attempted_clients_domains:
            sleep = 60 * 10
            pretty_print(f'No matches found. Sleeping for {sleep}s')
            time.sleep(sleep)
            continue

        for client in list_of_clients:
            client_id = client[0]
            client_name = client[1]
            group_of_clients_handlers[client_id] = [ClientsHandler(db_manager), client_name]

        #  MULTI-PROCESSING CODE
        try:
            print('running function...')
            executor.map(
                partial(run, group_of_clients_handlers=group_of_clients_handlers),
                list_of_not_attempted_clients_domains
            )
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

Despite all my attempts to debug this, I have no idea why this doesn't work, although I feel it relates to processes taking time to start up or scheduling task etc but I am not certain.
The while loop just keeps running and I see all the print statements like running function... but the run function never executes. The run function is a very large function with nested large functions.
The except block doesn't print out any error either. Would love to hear what you think...

ProcessPoolExecutor.map creates an iterator, you must consume the iterator to get the exception, otherwise the exception will be discarded.
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def raising_func(val):
  raise ValueError(val)

with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
  pool.map(raising_func, [1,2,3,4,5])

with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
  list(pool.map(raising_func, [1,2,3,4,5]))  # < ---- exception is thrown from here


Thanks @Ahmed AEK. I have finally seen the error. But now I need to solve that error lol. Here's a new question I created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78405637/multiprocessing-and-connection-pool-error-cannot-pickle-psycopg2-extensions-co
